# Invalid path to Chromedriver error on installing dependencies for Bagisto project

Tags: php, web, e-commerce

I using Open Server panel. [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ippsu.png)

I download project on Bagisto from git with this composer.json
https://codepen.io/AvKa/pen/dyQNxYv

On first time trying install i get this error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijNu3.png)

After uncommenting

```
extension = intl
```

Libs start installing [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8l0C.png)

And after installing I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxK7o.png)

I Googled for a long time but didn't find something like this

Comment: Please do not include images of errors, include the error text instead.